# Event for when a checkbox is unchecked in ExtJS?

Tags: events, checkbox, extjs

In ExtJS the **change** event is used for making something happen when a checkbox is checked, so, I'm wondering what event should be used to make something happen when the checkbox is unchecked?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same change event should fire when the checkbox is unchecked. Ext will pass the new value and the old value as params to your handler.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Checkbox.html#event-change